# NSTimer causing some weird delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

Ok my first app ever is a timer. Right after I made hello world as the convention seems to be. I am using the NSTimer class as my timer and I fire it every second and then I change the text in a UILabel. Now this all works very good except for my very first run. Each time I run the app in the simulator and I start the timer their is a weird delay on my last second, it will freeze for about 2 seconds and then continue as if nothing is wrong. And it then works for every set that runs.

Here is the code where I set up the NSTimer:

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then in the onTimer method I call updateLabel

```
countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", startMin,startSec];
//Check if sets are complete
if(setCount <= numOfSets)
{
    setLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Set %02d of %02d", setCount, numOfSets];
    //check if timer is complete
    if(startMin <= 0 && startSec <= 0)
    {
        countDownLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        //run interval timer when timer is complete
        if(intervalBetweenSets <= intervalBetweenSetsSetting)
        {
            setLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Starting set"];
            intervalBetweenSets++;
            intervalCounterSec--;
            countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:%02d", intervalCounterSec];
        }
        else
        {
            //RESET values on timer label
            TimerSettings *myTimer = [TimerSettings sharedManager ];
            startMin = myTimer.min;
            startSec = myTimer.sec;
            intervalBetweenSets = 0;
            intervalCounterSec = intervalBetweenSetsSetting+1;
            countDownLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", startMin,startSec];
            setLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Set %02d of %02d", setCount, numOfSets];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Actual timer for display
        if(startSec == 0)
        {
            startMin = startMin - 1;
        }
        startSec = startSec - 1;
        if(startSec == -1)
        {
            startSec = 59;
        }
        if(startMin <= 0 && startSec < 1)
        {
            //increment number of completed sets
            setCount++;
            //play sound when timer completes
            if (audioPlayer == nil)
                ;
            else
            {
                [audioPlayer play];
            }
        }

        countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", startMin,startSec];
    }
}
```

The thing is I don't know if it is some problem with the timer or if it has something to do with my logic, if anything is unclear of what I am doing please ask away and I will clarify.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "freeze"? The countdown display stops changing? The entire user interface won't respond to touches?

Comment: When I say freeze its only the label that stops updating, the rest of the app stays responsive. I have stepped through it and the logic appears sound, and I can set the timer to any values it will always freeze for two seconds on 00:01 and then continue as normal

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. The first firing of the timer is delayed by ~10 seconds and then each subsequent firing happens on the precise interval setting. Not very useful if the first firing happens late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use NSTimer to keep time if that is what you are trying to do, NSTimers are conceptually put into the event cue and so can only fire when your programming is waiting for input from the event cue. Yo can use NSTimers to tell you fields to update the display of itself but to get the amount of time passed you should either use NSDate methods or the equivelent C functions.

Comment: So basically what you are telling me is to run a while(true) kind of loop checking the date and then updating my label text accordingly? Is that true?

Comment: No, that would be over kill, still use an NSTimer but keep track of the time by recording the start time with `start = [NSDate date]` and then to get how much time has passed use `[start timeIntervalSinceNow]`, you then should change the text field value and send it a `[textView setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: But just to clarify a few things, why is it only the first run of the timer that freezes on 00:01. Every run after the first one runs perfectly. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does your code look like now, does it occur on an actual iPhone or just the simulator, if it is just the simulator, maybe your computer is low on memory and there is some cache swapping going on.

Comment: I am still waiting on apple approvement. Will update this as soon as I have tested on the device.

Comment: Ok I have tested the code on the actual device and it has no bugs, didn't change a thing. There must have been a problem with the memory as you suggested. Thanks